# Why does this regex used in findText gobble up the entire text as if it is greedy?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-docs

I can't for the life of me figure out why this regex is gobbling up the whole line in Google Docs. When I run this I can't get it to return just `{{ClientName}}`

Here is my text from my document.

`{{ClientName}} would like to have a {{Product}} {{done/created}}. The purpose of this {{Product}} is to {{ProductPurpose}}. We have experience with such testing and development, and will develop and test the {{Product}} for {{ClientName}}.`

```
function searchAndFind () {
     var foundText = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText('\{\{([^,\s}{][a-zA-Z]+)\}\}').getElement().asText().getText()
     return foundText
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

This is because `findText()` returns a `RangeElement` object, which provides methods for getting the full text `Element` as well as the `offset` of the actual matched text in the `Element`. When you use `getElement()`, you get the whole element instead of just the matched string.

#### Solution:

Get offsets from the range element to get the actual text in the element.

#### Code Snippet:

```
 function searchAndFind() {
  var rangeElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
    .getBody()
    .findText('{{([^,\\s]+)}}');

  return rangeElement
    .getElement()
    .asText()
    .getText()
    .substring(
      rangeElement.getStartOffset(),
      rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive()+1
    );
}
```

#### References:

- [FindText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findText(String))
- [RangeElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element)
- [String#Substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Thanks a million! I thought sure it was the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function searchAndFind () {
  var foundElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText('\{\{([^,\s}{][a-zA-Z]+)\}\}').getElement().asText().getText();
  var start=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText('\{\{([^,\s}{][a-zA-Z]+)\}\}').getStartOffset();
  var end=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText('\{\{([^,\s}{][a-zA-Z]+)\}\}').getEndOffsetInclusive();
  var foundText=foundElement.slice(start,end+1);
  Logger.log('\nfoundElement: %s\nstart: %s\nend: %s\nfoundText:%s\n',foundElement,start,end,foundText);
  return foundText;
```

Logger.log output:

```
[18-12-11 13:04:34:863 MST] 
foundElement: {{ClientName}} would like to have a {{Product}} {{done/created}}. The purpose of this {{Product}} is to {{ProductPurpose}}. We have experience with such testing and development, and will develop and test the {{Product}} for {{ClientName}}.
start: 0.0
end: 13.0
foundText:{{ClientName}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is 'greedy' by default. You can make a quantifier (ie. `+`,`?`,`*` or `{}`) non-greedy by following the quantifier with `?`.

For example:

- `x??`
- `x*?`
- `x+?`
- `x{n}?`
- `x{n,}?`
- `x{n,m}?`

Modify your regex to leverage this feature.

[Check out the regex documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and do a search (CTRL+F in chrome) for the term 'greedy' for more information.